# Import KVM XML to Qemu

Tags: linux, macos, qemu, kvm

If I qemu-system-x86_64 ~/Whonix-Gateway-11.0.0.3.0.qcow2 I can start the machine without networking, I see that there is an .xml file included in the directory

```
  <domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Debian</name>
  <description></description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  ....
```

How can I import it?

Answer (score 13):

That's not a "qemu" XML file; that's a file for importing the image into [libvirt](http://libvirt.org).

If you have a libvirt XML file, you can import it using the `virsh define` command:

```
virsh define /path/to/xmlfile.xml
```

This will define but not start the corresponding guest.  You can start it using `virsh start <name>`, or use a tool like `virt-manager`.  There is a `virsh create` command that will define *and start* the guest in a single command:

```
virsh create /path/to/xmlfile.xml
```

For these to work, of course, you need to have `libvirtd` running and you need to have appropriate permissions to access it.  If you want to have functional networking you may need to modify the domain XML description to match your local environment (or you may not, if the XML assumes the standard libvirt `default` network and you have that configured on your system).

Comment: Is there a way to start libvirtd on a os x? I have spent some time researching to no avail. It seems that Apple are quite anti-hypervisor in particular.

Comment: I don't know whether or not you could successfully run the libvirt daemon on OS X.  You could use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) if you're looking for a hypervisor that works on OS X.

Comment: How can I import the xml file in Virtualbox then? Seems like there is no easy solution, thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, you can't import the libvirt xml into virtualbox.  You would have to create a vm manually, and configure it to boot from your disk image.